# Checkmarx/Sonar Security Scan

Tags: java, spring-boot, veracode, checkmarx

I have `csrf().disable()` in my Security config and `checkmarx/Sonar/Veracode`  scans is complaining about it.

Any workaround for this issue other than using `security.enable-csrf` since it was deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the CXRules to allow this. Or mark it as a False Positive